# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’m a noob in python 3. I’ve looked extensively for the solution of my problem but I couldn’t understand why the method .seek() doesn't work.
I want to do a program that copy the information of one archive to the final of another archive. I know that I could do with appending or other methods but, in fact, what intrigue me it's why the attributeerror happen in this program.

Thanks in advance.

```
from sys import argv
script, from_file, to_file=argv
print(f"Are you sure that you want to copy {from_file} to {to_file}?")
print("Ready hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort")
input()
origin_file=""
final_file=""

try:
  file1=open(from_file,'r')
  file2=open(to_file,'r+')
  file1=file1.read()

except:
  print('There is not a file')

file2.seek(0,2)
file2.write(file1)

print(final_file)
```

Resolved: I can't use seek with string object.:):)

Comment: You are trying to call seek on a string, you read the file with `final_file=file2.read()`. Perhaps you wanted to use `file2.seek()`?

Comment: If you wanted to add data to the end of a file, open it in append mode: `'a'`. Then just write, no seeking needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final_file=file2.read() <---- return string...
```

String object in Python don't have seek function. Probably you try seek file. You had open two file file1 and file2. Probably you try seek file2. Just try `file2.seek(0,2)`